# CSV to JSON, creating an array from columns

Tags: python, arrays, json, csv, dictionary

I have sample csv data that looks like this:

```
id,hex1,hex2,hex3,hex4,hex5
388,#442c1c,#927450,#664c31,#22110c,
387,#6a442f,#826349,,,
1733,#4d432e,#75623f,,,
1728,#393e46,#5f4433,#ad7a52,#362c28,#a76042
```

I'd like to create JSON data from this csv that looks something like this:

```json
{
  "images":[
    {
      "colors": [
        "#442c1c",
        "#2f4f4f",
        "#927450",
        "#696969",
        "#664c31",
        "#556b2f"
      ],
      "id": "388"
    }
  ]
}
```

Each row should take the first column (id) and create a dictionary/array (sorry, not sure of the correct terminology) containing the hex values within that row. Python is the langauge I'm most familiar with so I'd prefer to use that to create my JSON.

Can anyone suggest some starting points?

Thank you in advance.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use the following that basically is a list comprehension:

```py
import csv

with open('file.csv', mode='r') as csv_file:
    reader = csv.DictReader(csv_file)
    next(reader, None)  # skip the header
    # id,hex1,hex2,hex3,hex4,hex5
    images = [{'colors': [row[f'hex{n}'] for n in range(1, 6) if row[f'hex{n}'] != ''], 'id': row["id"]} for row in reader]

d = {'images': images}
```

`d` will contain the dictionary you want:

```py
{'images': [{'colors': ['#6a442f', '#826349'], 'id': '387'},
            {'colors': ['#4d432e', '#75623f'], 'id': '1733'},
            {'colors': ['#393e46', '#5f4433', '#ad7a52', '#362c28', '#a76042'],
             'id': '1728'}]}
```